# How to cast Moq object to check type for dependency injection

Tags: c#, casting, moq

I have created a wrapper class for the Microsoft DependencyInjection to simplify some of the calls in my application. I am trying to write unit tests that use Moq to insert objects into the dependency injection service.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

public static class DiService
{
    private static IServiceProvider diProvider;
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> mockCollection = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static IServiceCollection ServiceCollection { get; } = new ServiceCollection();
    public static bool UseTestMode { get; set; } = false;

    public static T GetRequiredService<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        if( UseTestMode )
        {
            if( mockCollection.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) )
            {
                return mockCollection[typeof(T)] as T;
            }
        }

        if( diProvider == null )
        {
            diProvider = ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        return diProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }

    public static void RegisterMock(Type interfaceType, object mockObjectInstance)
    {
        if( !mockObjectInstance.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(interfaceType) )
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"mockObjectInstance must be of type {interfaceType}");
        }

        if( mockCollection.ContainsKey(interfaceType) )
        {
            mockCollection[interfaceType] = mockObjectInstance;
        }
        else
        {
            mockCollection.Add(interfaceType, mockObjectInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing related code

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
}

public class TestClass : ITestInterface
{
}

[Fact]
public void GetRequiredService_MoqObject_NormalOperation()
{
    Mock<ITestInterface> mock = new Mock<ITestInterface>();

    DiService.UseTestMode = true;
    DiService.RegisterMock(typeof(ITestInterface), mock.Object);

    ITestInterface testResult = DiService.GetRequiredService<ITestInterface>();

    Assert.NotNull(testResult);
}
```

This works great for mocks that I great myself, but not when I try to use Moq. The `InvalidCastException` is thrown for Moq objects.

In the `RegisterMock` method, I haven't been able to figure out how to cast the Moq object to check if it implements the proper interface. The Moq object actually doesn't inherit from the interface it's mocking (the interface is `ITestInterfaceProxy`). I also can't figure out how to cast an object to a type specified by a variable.

Is there any way to actually perform the error check in `RegisterMock`?

Thanks ahead of time for your responses.

Addendum:
Based on Peter Csala's comment, I am adding this example of how I'm using the `DiService` above. I hope I haven't simplified it to the point of uselessness.

```
[Fact]
public void TestLoad()
{
    DiService.UseTestMode = true;
    Mock<IDataAccess> mockDataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
    DiService.RegisterMock(typeof(IDataAccess), mockDataAccess.Object);
    Data testData = GenFu.A.New<Data>();

    mockDataAccess.Setup(mock => mock.LoadData(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(testData);

    // Assuming that inside MyViewModel.LoadData there is some process that generates an IDataAccess and calls IDataAccess.LoadData
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    Data loadedData = viewModel.LoadData("some id");

    Assert.Equal(testData, loadedData); 
}
```

Comment: Wait what??? Do you want to test a class which works differently in normal mode and during testing? Why?

Comment: Well, when you are testing a class that has its dependencies injected, it is pretty common to mock up those dependencies. In that sense, the class's production dependencies are different form the ones tested, and so yes, technically it is different. The point is to test the logic in the class aside from the dependencies.
What I have above is meant to provide the means to provided the injected dependency while testing those other classes, and I'm just trying to prove that it works through a unit test.

Comment: I should also say, I haven't found a way to inject the Moq object into the dependency injection service through the normal route because the Moq object doesn't inherit from the interface that it's mocking. Oh, and the DI service automatically creates an instance of the required object. I don't want that when I'm testing. I want a specific object injected that I can manipulate.

Comment: Have you heard of AutoFixture https://autofixture.github.io/ ? I think it might do what you're trying to with your wrapper

Comment: @LLL Thanks, I'll have to take a closer look at AutoFixture. It sounds similar to GenFu, which is what I've been using. I want to get away from GenFu because it is so poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify certain things:

> I am trying to write unit tests that use Moq to insert objects into the dependency injection service

**In case of unit testing the DI is not in use**. Rather you explicitly pass the mocked object to your system under test. For example:

Your System under test class

```
private readonly IDependency dependency;
public SampleUsage(IDependency dep)
  => dependency = dep;
```

Your test code

```
//Arrange
Mock<IDependency> mockedDep = new Mock<IDependency>();
mockedDep.Setup(...).Returns(...);

var sut = SampleUsage(mockedDep.Object);

//Act
var actualResult = sut.XYZMethod();
```

---

In case of integration or end-to-end testing you rely on the DI system, but not by replacing some components with a mocked one. Rather you are using different configuration options.

For example if you have a component that communicates with a 1st or 3rd party REST service then you should change the base address configuration of that service. That new address should point to a locally running http mock server. You can create one with a library like [WireMock.NET](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net).